# Getting the FB like to grab right URL

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am using an Facebook like button within an iFrame in my Fancybox, for my site I use Zenphoto. This seems to only way to make the like button show up in Fancybox.

The code:

```
    this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?    href=http://www.dagloos.com' + this.href +         '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
```

When someone clicks the like button now, a blank like notification shows on the facebook page, with the direct img url. I added the og tags to the header of my website, but it doesn't grab them when liking. Probably because the iFrame version is outdated.

How could I make it that the like shows up on facebook with the image thumbnail and if even possible, the rest of the information (site title, desc. etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=type in ur web address here"
         scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
         style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

After href type in your web address here